# WTSINFO's LastInputTime

Tags: c++, terminal-services

I'm trying to calculate the session's idle time using WTSINFO's LastInputTime.
I called WTSQuerySessionInformation with WTSSessionInfo but the LastInputTime I get is the DisconnectTime.
I was expecting it to be CurrentTime (or very close) since there's input until I'm running the code.
Anyone has any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the session disconnected? (Sorry if this question sounds a bit obvious!)

Comment: No, it's the (only) currently active user session

Comment: Is the session a remote session or a console session?

Comment: Yep, that's most likely the issue -- fetching idle times for the console session with WTSQuerySessionInformation is pretty unreliable on Windows 7+. See [Cassia issue 23](https://code.google.com/p/cassia/issues/detail?id=23) and [this related forum post](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/beca90b0-8abd-4f26-a3bb-a146e11da1b6/idle-time-fails-for-nonrdp-terminals).

Comment: Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: It says there to use WinStationIdleTime for console sessions but the only place I see it's relevant is in RpcWinStationQueryInformation, and I have no idea what dll exports this function

Comment: RpcWinStationQueryInformation is part of the RPC internals of Remote Desktop Services. You could run a process in the console session that calls [GetLastInputInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646302(v=vs.85).aspx) -- I'm not sure what other options there are, though I'd love to hear there's an easier one out there!